# I get this exception after the project run with my flutter project

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, dart-pub

This is the first time I use the flutter firebase. I have done all the necessary steps for the project and put everything in the right place. But I get this error every time I run the project.

This is the link of my project : https://github.com/hmoodaps/chat_app

> E/flutter (15196): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)]
>
> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nonnull field "apiKey" is null., ExecutionException, Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nonnull field "apiKey" is null.,
>
> Stacktrace: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nonnull field "apiKey" is null.
> E/flutter (15196):  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:5)
> E/flutter (15196):  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:9)
> E/flutter (15196):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.lambda$initializeCore$3$io-flutter-plugins-firebase-core-FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin(FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:183)
> E/flutter (15196):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.run(Unknown Source:4)
> E/flutter (15196):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
> E/flutter (15196):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
> E/flutter (15196):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
> E/flutter (15196): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nonnull field "apiKey" is null.
> E/flutter (15196):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore$PigeonFirebaseOptions.setApiKey(GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:69)
> E/flutter (15196):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore$PigeonFirebaseOptions$Builder.build(GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:318)
> E/flutter (15196):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.firebaseOptionsToMap(FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:67)
> E/flutter (15196):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.lambda$firebaseAppToMap$0$io-flutter-plugins-firebase-core-FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin(FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:82)

Since the API exists and there are no problems, I think the filter code should work correctly